# Fermat's theorem for $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose that $f$ is a differentiable function in an open set $E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, and that $f$ has a local maximum at a point $\mathbf{x}\in E$. Prove that $f'(\mathbf{x})=0.$

I am sorry if this topic is repeated but I solved this myself and 
I would like to know is it correct?

**Proof:** Since function $f$ is differentiable at $\mathbf{x}$ then: $$f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{h})-f(\mathbf{x})=A\mathbf{h}+r(\mathbf{h}),$$ where $A=f'(\mathbf{x})\in L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^1)$ and $\dfrac{|r(\mathbf{h})|}{|\mathbf{h}|}\to 0$ as $\mathbf{h}\to \mathbf{0}$.

Fix $j\in \{1,2\,\dots,n\}$ and let $\mathbf{h}=t\mathbf{e}_j$. Then $$f(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{e}_j)-f(\mathbf{x})=At\mathbf{e}_j+r(t\mathbf{e}_j),$$ $$\dfrac{f(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{e}_j)-f(\mathbf{x})}{t}=A\mathbf{e}_j+\dfrac{r(t\mathbf{e}_j)}{t}.$$ Letting $t\to 0$ we get $(D_kf)(\mathbf{x})=f'(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{e}_j.$

Since $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)=\text{locmax}f$ then $\exists \delta>0$ such that for any $\mathbf{y}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $|\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}|<\delta$ we have $f(\mathbf{y})\leqslant f(\mathbf{x}).$ In particular, for any $\mathbf{y}=(y_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ with $|y_1-x_1|<\delta$ we have $f(y_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\leqslant f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$.

Put $g_1(t)=f(t,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ then $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and $g_1(t)$ has local maximum at $\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{e}_1=x_1$. Then using 1D of Fermat's theorem case we get: $g'(x_1)=0$ hence $(D_1f)(\mathbf{x})=0$. Making analogous reasonings we get: $(D_jf)(\mathbf{x})=0$. Hence $f'(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{e}_j=(D_j f)(\mathbf{x})=0$. Thus for any $\mathbf{h}\in \mathbb{R^n}$ we have $f'(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{h}=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $f'(\mathbf{x})=0$

Comment: Yeah it is right.

Comment: @Vim, Thanks for checking!