# How do I prove that a scalar is a maximum if the derivative with respect to a vector is zero?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

To illustrate my point, How would I prove the scalar $a$ is a maximum if the following equals zero.

$$\frac{da}{d\vec v} = (\frac{\partial a}{\partial v_{1}} \frac{\partial a}{\partial v_{2}} \frac{\partial a}{\partial v_{3}}.....) = (0 \space 0\space 0\space 0.....)$$

I can't seem to proof that the maximum must fulfil this condition which is why I hoped for help.

Comment: I believe your notation is wrong. First take partial derivatives and then substitute a. If function is multidimensional then a is also a vector.

Comment: Do you want to prove that the function reaches maximum if the partial derivatives are zero? Or do you want to prove that the partial derivatives are zeros if the function reaches maximum?

* The former does not hold ($f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ at $(0,0)$).
* The latter holds, and the proof is easy once you note that, at the maximum point, the function also reaches maximum as a function of any *one* variable $v_i$ (i.e. keep all $v_j, j\ne i$ fixed and only vary $v_i$, and use the equivalent theorem for functions of a single variable).

Comment: @StinkingBishop I would like to prove the that the partial derivatives are zeros if the function reaches maximum.

Comment: @cojoye (a) Your title and the first line of the body of the question are saying the opposite, please edit; (b) Please see the second part of my comment, does it answer your question?

Comment: @StinkingBishop Apologies for the title, I was hoping for a proof of why the function also reaches maximum as a function of any one variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If a differentiable scalar function $f$ reaches maximum at $x$, then the derivative at $x$ is zero. The idea is that suppose it is not zero, then we can move a little along the direction along the positive entry of $\nabla f$ and gets a bigger value. If none of the direction is positive, we just move along the opposite direction of a negative direction. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1645716/306553)'s a link which included a proof of it.
- If the derivative is zero, it is not true that it must be a maximum. Consider the function $y=x^2$.
- If the derivative is zero and the Hessian is negative semidefinite, then we have a local maximum. [Here](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~yaron/AM221/lecture_notes/AM221_lecture9.pdf)'s a link to the proof.